# Displaying HTML and Web Pages consecutivelyin VB.net using Web Browser conctrol

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of Web Pages and LOCAL HTML files that I want to display using the Web Browser control in a VB.Net application. I set the navigate property from the first file in my array and I get to it OK. I want to stay there for some interval, then display the next one. I set a timer after I navigate to the first one then want to navigate to the second one after the timer pop but It flashes the first one then the second one. Is there  method I can use to hold the first one for some interval, then display the second, then the third ETC?

Thanks
Bill

Comment: If timer.tick is what is navigating the browser to the next page, and you are creating/starting the timer after the first page has loaded, then as soon as the timer starts it's going to navigate to the next page which is why the first may appear to flash by and then the second pops up. I would try starting the timer first, and include your first page as one of its ticks. Then all the page loads will be evenly spaced out, including the first one

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Appreciate the come back...